# Need help creating expect condition on webdriver.io

Tags: javascript, webdriver, ui-automation

I'm testing a web application that uses a progress bar to reflect the state of some lengthy process.

I need to create a test that clicks the Start button and then waits for the progress bar to reach 75%. Then the test should click Stop. 5% is the acceptable tolerance limit to pass the test.

But I'm not sure how to create an assertion to check this, I already created the test, and it stops at 75%, but how can I (using Mocha and the expected wdio library) can verify if it's in the 5% acceptable tolerance limit?

This is what I have right now that it is working:

```
describe('Progress bar challenge', () => {

    before(() => {
        ProgressPage.open();
    });

    it('Should click [start] wait for the bar to reach 75% and click [stop]', async () => {

            await ProgressPage.startBtn.click(); 
            await ProgressPage.progressBar.waitUntil(async function () {
                return (await this.getAttribute('aria-valuenow')) >= '75'
            }, {
                timeout: 50000,
            });
            await ProgressPage.stopBtn.click();
            console.log(await ProgressPage.progressBar.getAttribute('aria-valuenow'));        
    });
    
});
```

The log usually returns 75 or 76, but I don't know which assertion I can create to pass the test.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code this will have tolerance of 5%

```
it('Progress bar start wait stop and tollerence', async () => {
    await ProgressPage.open()
    await ProgressPage.startButton.click()
    await ProgressPage.progressBar.waitUntil(async function() {
        const tolerance = (await this.getAttribute('aria-valuenow'))
        return ( tolerance >= '75' && tolerance <= '80' )
    },
    {
        timeout: 50000,
        timeoutmsg:"Failed while waiting for progressBar to reach 75%"
    })
    await ProgressPage.stopButton.click()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I follow correctly, but if you import chai

```
   const { assert } = require('chai')
   const progressValue = await this.getAttribute('aria-valuenow')
```

and then do

```
assert(progressValue >= '75' && progressValue <= '80')
```